# Slide div smoothly? Div slides nice, but the content (inner divs) lags behind

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm a newbie to javascript and I've read a lot of threads on getting divs to slide smoothly, but while my div slides nicely, the inner content of that div (which is contained in multiple inner divs) doesn't load fast enough so I get a  gap for a second as the outer div slides all the way out.

[GIF to describe what I'm talking about.](http://recordit.co/vPvsu7DfiK)

I'm not sure if this is something that is fixable, but thought I would ask the JS gurus here about it anyway.

My JS:

```
  $('#display-map-info').click(function () {
      if ($('#map-functions').hasClass('visible')) {
          $('#map-functions').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
          $('#map-functions').removeClass('visible');
      }
      else {
          $('#map-functions').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
          $('#map-functions').addClass('visible');
      }
  });
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="map-toolbar">
        <button id="display-map-info"></button>
        <button id="classifyHab"></button>
        <button id="download-data"></button>
</div>
<div class="visible" id="map-functions">
        Select data year to display: <br />
        <select id="data-year"></select>
        <div id="legendDiv">
            <div id="legend"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="layersDiv">
            <h5>Layers</h5>
            <div id="toggleLayers">
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="patchesLyr" name="patchesLayer" value="patches" />Habitat Patches</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="protectCoverLyr" name="pcLayer" value="pc">Protective Cover</label>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="faLyr" name="faLayer" value="fa" checked>Focal & Reference Areas</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rendererDiv">
            <h5>Renderers</h5>
            <label><input type="radio" id="qhStatusLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="qhStatus" checked>Quail Habitat Status</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id="coarseHabLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="coarse">Coarse-level Habitat Types</label>
            <label><input type="radio" id="fineHabLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="fine">Fine-level Habitat Types</label><br />
            <h5>Opacity</h5>
            <input type="radio" id="100-percent" name="setOpacity" value="100" checked>0%
            <input type="radio" id="75-percent" name="setOpacity" value="25">25%
            <input type="radio" id="50-percent" name="setOpacity" value="50">50%
            <input type="radio" id="25-percent" name="setOpacity" value="75">75%
        </div>
        <div id="HabClassifyGPService">
            State: <br />
            <select id="stateAbbrev" name="stateIDList" form="uploadForm">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Lousiana</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            </select>
            <form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label class="custom-file-upload">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="dataUpload" />
                    <span id="fileUploadLabel">File Upload</span>
                </label>
                <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload" />
            </form>
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-toolbar button {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
}

#map-functions {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 93.90%;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: try to add `overflow : hidden;` to `#map-functions`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef That helped a lot, thanks! Here is a new GIF - do you know if it's part of the animation that it shortens the height of the div a little bit and still creates that gap (watch near the bottom of the GIF)? Still, it looks much much better. http://recordit.co/BiWFbu1O26

Comment: you can play with decrease `height: 93.90%;` or remove it , increase `bottom:0` and I think `overflow-x : hidden` is better than `overflow : hidden`

Comment: And its depending on the result of the div . if you have another gif with expected result I can help you better .. but any way 1st: remove `height: 93.90%;` use `top:` to push the div from the top and `bottom` to push the div from the bottom .. and again use `overflow-x : hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this .. with `toggle` and `toggleClass` instead of `if/else`

```js
$('#display-map-info').click(function () {
    $('#map-functions').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
body{
  background : red;
}
#map-functions {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  right: 50px;
  top : 20px; /* change here */
  bottom: 20px; /* change here */
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 5px solid orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>

<div id="map-toolbar">
  <button id="display-map-info">slide Div</button>
  <button id="classifyHab"></button>
  <button id="download-data"></button>
</div>
<div class="visible" id="map-functions">
  Select data year to display: <br />
  <select id="data-year"></select>
  <div id="legendDiv">
      <div id="legend"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="layersDiv">
      <h5>Layers</h5>
      <div id="toggleLayers">
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="patchesLyr" name="patchesLayer" value="patches" />Habitat Patches</label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="protectCoverLyr" name="pcLayer" value="pc">Protective Cover</label>
          <label><input type="checkbox" id="faLyr" name="faLayer" value="fa" checked>Focal & Reference Areas</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="rendererDiv">
      <h5>Renderers</h5>
      <label><input type="radio" id="qhStatusLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="qhStatus" checked>Quail Habitat Status</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="coarseHabLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="coarse">Coarse-level Habitat Types</label>
      <label><input type="radio" id="fineHabLyr" name="chosenLayer" value="fine">Fine-level Habitat Types</label><br />
      <h5>Opacity</h5>
      <input type="radio" id="100-percent" name="setOpacity" value="100" checked>0%
      <input type="radio" id="75-percent" name="setOpacity" value="25">25%
      <input type="radio" id="50-percent" name="setOpacity" value="50">50%
      <input type="radio" id="25-percent" name="setOpacity" value="75">75%
  </div>
  <div id="HabClassifyGPService">
      State: <br />
      <select id="stateAbbrev" name="stateIDList" form="uploadForm">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Lousiana</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      </select>
      <form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label class="custom-file-upload">
              <input type="file" name="file" id="dataUpload" />
              <span id="fileUploadLabel">File Upload</span>
          </label>
          <input type="button" value="Upload" id="upload" />
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** if the div affect with another style after being visible .. then check the class `.visible` style on your css file

Comment: I removed the `height` property and replaced it with `top: 65px` to push it down (I left `bottom: 0` as I want the div to extend to the bottom of the page, though I did test it with `bottom: 40px`), I also changed to `overflow-x`, but the result is the same as the second GIF I linked to in my comment on my original post. I still get a momentary gap when it slides in and out, and it shortens the div when it slides in for some reason.

Comment: I commented out my `border` and `padding` properties and that fixes it for some reason. It now slides without the weird gap/shrinking behavior. Hmm.